# Why System.out.println(new String(copyTo))?

Tags: java, println

I was studying the Java tutorials here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

However a doubt appeared:

Why do I need the `new String()`? Is there any potential problem of using directly `System.out.println(copyTo)`? I thought that under the hood the println already had the toString method that converts to strings.

```
   class ArrayCopyOfDemo {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        char[] copyFrom = {'d', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e',
            'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd'};
            
        char[] copyTo = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(copyFrom, 2, 9);
        
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
      }
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it to just `System.out.println(copyTo)` and looking at the result that is being printed?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS what does it show? [There's no difference for `char[]`](https://ideone.com/hj1owZ), because `PrintStream` has an overload for `char[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `new String(copyTo)` there. `copyTo` would suffice.

In general, you don't want to invoke `println` on an array. For example:

```
System.out.println(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

wouldn't print `[1, 2, 3]` or `123`, but rather something like `[I@243432`. This is because there is no special overload for `int[]` (or other array types, except for `char[]`), so `println(Object)` is used. This invokes `toString()` on the parameter; but arrays don't have useful `toString()` implementations.

However, the [`PrintStream.println(char[])` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-) does work *somewhat* sensibly, and produces an output as if the `char[]` were converted to a `String` first (but note that the `toString()` method *isn't* used to produce this: no `String` is created from the array).

```
 System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
 System.out.println(copyTo);
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/hj1owZ):

```
caffein
caffein
```

I suspect it's just an oversight/bug in the documentation that `new String` is used. I filed a bug report with Oracle to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

yes you're right. `System.out.println()` first cast passed object to String by `String.valueOf()‍‍` and this method calls `toString‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍` method of object.
so you can print `copyTo` without `new String()`.

Comment: This explanation is somewhat misleading, as `String.valueOf()` has also an overloaded variant for `char[]`. Try `System.out.println(String.valueOf(copyTo));`  vs `System.out.println(copyTo.toString());` to see the difference.

Comment: thank you @GyroGearless. you'r right. i missed that "copyTo" is array. should i delete this?

Answer (score 0):

The `new String()` initializes the new object of the String with the same sequence of characters as the argument passed, in this case, the argument is copyTo.
Firstly, the required number of characters are getting copied into the array copyTo. And this array is passed to the function String. The String function will create a word from the array copyTo. And the keyword `new` is used to create a new instance(object) of the String as String is a class in Java.

You can do the same thing using `System.out.println(copyTo);` as well. This will only work for the array of the type char.